# Can't find my .log file using slf4j+logback

Tags: java, maven, logback, slf4j

First you must know that i'm a beginner with logback so maybe i am making an error really stupid and not noticing it .Then maybe the problem might have been solved somewhere else but as long as i have searched i found nothing .

But i have a problem when i try to configure my logs file .
I want to have a repository on the root of my project called logs with all my logs ordered by time (and a limit size) . So i saw that logback is using what i want with `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy`.

So after some research on google my config file ( logback.xml ) is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="ROLLING"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>SG.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- each file should be at most 100MB, keep 60 days worth of history, 
            but at most 20GB -->
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Also my pom.xml looks like that :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>testLog</groupId>
<artifactId>testLog</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And of course i call the logger  :

```
package testLog;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {
   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       logger.debug("toto");
       logger.info("ela ela");
       logger.warn("ce je ne sais quoi ");
       logger.error("ce dont du ciel qui la rend belle");
   }
}
```

So now i can tell you my problem : No log file is generated .
Do you have any idea what the problem could be ?

Thanks for your time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it should be at your project's root, to make sure it is generated, instead of:

```
<file>SG.log</file>
```

try to give an absolute path, such as

```
<file>/Users/username/logs/SG.log</file>
```

Make sure the directory arborescence is created.
This way you know where to look for the file, and you can make sure it is actually created.

If it is well generated then do:

```
<file>logs/SG.log</file>
```

And it should go to your log directory (create the directory manually to be sure, I don't think logback would create it)

**EDIT**

Could you change your root logger to be

```
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
</root>
```

maybe one of the others `STDOUT` and `FILE` are hijacking the logs

**EDIT2**

The last think I can think of which are different from my configuration are these:

- My logback.xml file starts this way

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE configuration>
  <configuration debug="true">
  ```
- I set the class for the encoder

  ```
  <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%msg%n</Pattern>
  </encoder>
  ```

---

Also "ce **don** du ciel qui la rend belle" :)

Comment: thanks for your quick response , but this did not do the trick , i tried with the absolute path and no file is generated . btw thanks i corrected "ce don du ciel qui la rend belle"  ;)

Comment: Do logs appear on the console? with your `STDOUT` appender

Comment: however, i don't understand why the logs still appear in the console while i asked for a RollingFileAppender

Comment: I edited my answer, can you try to remove the STDOUT and FILE appenders from your root logger

Comment: I tried but still nothing , and still the logs in the console

Comment: Still not working .  I understand , thank you for your time :)

Comment: I copy pasted your appender on my logback.xml and it work fine, creating an `SG.log` file at the root of my project

Comment: Here are the libraries I imported: `ch.qos.logback.logback-classic` version 1.2.3, `ch.qos.logback.logback-core` version 1.2.3, 
`org.slf4j.slf4j-api` version: 1.7.25, maybe try these versions, I am sure they work for me.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution of my problem (another problem appeared but will solve it soon )

I don't know if it is the version given by Bentaye or just the fact that i added the ressources in my classpath and now i have reponse !

Magical !

Thanks everybody if you have tried :)